# How do I turn "sudo apt-get" text into clickable download links in Firefox?

Tags: software-recommendation, firefox, apt

In support forums, tech blogs or any other website, one may encounter some instruction similar to the following:

> Type `sudo apt-get install sl` in a terminal window, enter your password en you should get your program.

I know the risk implied by installing additional software and I promise I will be careful. So how do I make Firefox understand that whenever it displays such a text, it should turn it into a link wich, when cliked on, will open the Software Center on the right page?

Answer (score 4):

The solution comprises two steps:

1. connect firefox and apt-get
2. modify `apt-get install` textual content of web pages into hyperlinks pointing to `apt://...`

Regarding the first step, there's [apturl](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) to handle hyperlinks that implement the `apt://` "protocol".

Regarding the second step, you could use the [greasemonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) together with a greasemonkey script that modifies the page content as desired. I didn't test it myself, but there are different examples to do this only, for example the ["Apt-Linker for Greasemonkey" script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47591).